# What happens to micro SD cards when they get worn out?

Tags: micro-sd-card, lifespan

So most are speaking and asking what's the lifetime of a micro SD card or an SSD drive. But I barely found information what happens when a micro SD card actually gets worn out.

Does anybody know this? My understanding was that after the lifetime of a micro SD card is over, it only becomes a read only card, which means you could basically copy it to a new one of the same size and go again. But I think some people had cases where data actually becomes corrupt and unreadable too.

So how is it really?

Comment: Both are possible.

Comment: I have rarely had SD cards fail in read-only mode. Usually they get corrupted and start behaving erratically or just stop working altogether (fail to be recognized and become inaccessible). SSDs behave more predictably (as well as having longer lifespans in general).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are are correct.
You won’t lose your data from the SD card when it has become unwritable, because the software stops you from writing so you have a chance to recover your data.
If you can’t write to your SD card, it is broken, so buy a new one and transfer the data to your new SD card.

Comment: Whatever was in the process of being written can be lost, though.

Answer (score 0):

SSD and and SD cards do have limited writes and if the drive fails for that reason there is a good chance the data will be recoverable. But never rely on this. Like any electronic component these devices can fail at any time for a variety of reasons and often do so without any warning. The maximum writes on modern SSDs is very high and is difficult to exceed under normal conditions. There are many opportunities for the drive to fail for some other reason.

I recently experienced an SSD failure. It had been working fine with no SMART warnings. Then one morning I discovered the computer was displaying a boot failure in the BIOS. The OS is Windows 10 and I suspected the drive had failed after a scheduled restart after an OS update. I booted Macrium reflect from a flash drive and the only drives shown were the flash drive and the drive containing the image backup. The SSD was not recognized at all. I replaced the drive and recovered the OS from a previously created image and everything worked.

Bottom line is you cannot make any assumptions about when or how an SSD or SD card will fail. It may fail at any time with no chance of recovery. If the drive contains important data then you need to make regular backups.